# Is it possible to prevent the screen from locking while connected to the USB

Tags: htc-sense, usb, lock-screens, htc-desire-z

Generally when there is a USB cable attached to the phone it's not in my pocket, so the screen lock isn't doing anything usefull for me and I'd like to disable it.

Comment: it's actually a desire z, but there is no tag for that and I don't have enough rep to make tags

Comment: Tag updated for you!

Comment: The question can be phone agnostic. The answer works on any android device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go into **Settings > Applications > Development** there is a setting for **Stay Wake** which is described as "Screen will never sleep while charging".

Give that a try :)